# How can i find out what gameserver i am connected to?

Tags: networking, proxy, cloudflare

I am currently playing Tarkov and i was curious where the server i got matched to is located. I tried using netstat to check where the PID leads to, but it only showed up as a cloudflare server in america.

Am i overlooking something? I thought that, even when cloudflare proxies my traffic to the server, i should somehow be able to trace where the traffic comes from? Though now when i think about it, that does kind of sound like what a proxy does - i hope someone can enlighten me a bit more about this question

Answer (score 0):

Try using a proper network sniffer.  I doubt any games tunnel all traffic through cloudflare unless they are flash games or something like that... Pretty sure it would cause issues when the site undergoes UAM.

Comment: Cloudflare does offer TCP/UDP tunneling services now, they're just quite a bit more expensive than the usual HTTP proxying.

Comment: How does that work with that much traffic? I also dont understand why it is showing CloudFlare Servers located in the US - im in Europe, so wouldnt tunneling through an american server give me a huge latency increase? I really want to understand how cloudflare operates here

Comment: I've only ever seen cloudflare for HTTP Proxy and in the US (with exception of course for the cloudflare public DNS server)